# Making a PATCH request from one machine to another

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, python-requests, portforwarding

I currently have a python app running on a RPi connected to laptop #1. I used

`ssh -Nf -L localhost:9999:localhost:5000 pi@raspberrypi.local`

to forward any requests from laptop #1 to the RPi and can successfully make PATCH requests in the form of

`curl -X PATCH "http://localhost:9999/pins/1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"state\": \"on\"}"`

(This just turns a LED pin on)

Anyways, I want to make the same request but from another laptop, laptop #2 (and hopefully any other machine so that the lights can be changed from anywhere). I tried just switching the localhost to laptop #1's IP address, but that did not work. I believe the port 9999 is open for listening, when I use

`netstat -a | grep -i "listen"`

I get back:

`ssh     16551 joshwh    8u  IPv6 0x37a4856739271d0d      0t0  TCP [::1]:distinct (LISTEN)`

`ssh     16551 joshwh    9u  IPv4 0x37a4856735b5ec1d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:distinct (LISTEN)`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: bind your RPi service to "0.0.0.0:5000" instead of "localhost:5000" then you will be able to connect to port 5000 of RPI  from any device on local network without the use of tunneling and without dependency on laptop #1. Also [see last case in ssh forwarding pitfalls to share your tunnel to laptop#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61286246/12396017)

Comment: How would I make requests to the Pi from a machine not on the local network?

Comment: it depends. if your "home" router has real IP address on WAN interface then you could just configure port forwarding at your router, assign some domain name to such IP address, install letsencrypt certificate on it and provide people with nice https URL and all people around the world could play with your leds. but if your ISP does not provide you with real IP or you are talking about bunch of RPi devices and  you have no control over multiple routers/networks(where those RPi devices reside) in different locations then it is another story.

Comment: I am connected to my apartment building's public WiFi so I can't mess around with port forwarding on the router. Could I not send the request to some kind of external connection that laptop #1 could pick up?